# Carcassone - placing barn figure in field

Tags: carcassonne

Game : Carcassone with expansion "[Abbey & Mayor](https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0994/3066/products/carcassonne-abbey-mayor-paplasinajums-galda-spele_large.png?v=1516808613)".

Question - theoretically barn can be placed:

**A)** only if my farmer has already been placed in field?

**B)** regarding if any farmers already exist in fields?
[image: barn placment]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [rules](https://images-cdn.zmangames.com/us-east-1/filer_public/48/90/48909233-453b-446f-bbb6-3aee9058a41b/zm7815_carcassonne_exp5_rules.pdf), the barn can be placed in a field as long as that field doesn't already have a barn. Farmers are no concern when placing the barn:

> *You may place your barn on a field already occupied by farmers.* You may not,
>   however, place your barn on a field already occupied by another barn. Once
>   placed, a barn remains in play until the end of the game.